# Converting a ADB command to Java

Tags: java, android

I need to convert the below ADB command such that it could be executed from a button on the activity interface.

```
adb shell dumpsys meminfo com.google.android.apps.maps -d > meminfo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute shell commands like this

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dumpsys meminfo com.google.android.apps.maps -d | tee sdcard/meminfo.txt");
```

Comment: I tried using the command but the file do not get created. Is the device needed to be rooted to perform this task?

Comment: you need to check your logs. what exception/error it is giving

Comment: Command gets executed without any error but the file don't get created